# How to get from a date column the last date of the previous month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have two date columns, which takes into account only working days. A_date and E_date.
E_date is calculated adding +2 days to A_date, because that's the request

The problem is that if the day of A_date is 30th or 31st of the month, then E_date date needs to be the last day of the current month, and not the first or second working day of the next month.

i have tried eomonth function but that does not work because it would need a explicit date.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: *How* have you tried `EOMONTH()`?

Comment: I am working on ssms

Comment: @Enrico . . . Your title has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I found a solution in the end
`update #date
set a_date =
case 
when day(a_date) in (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08) and day(e_date) in (24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31) 
then DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,e_date)+1,0))
 else a_date
end`

Answer (score 0):

> How to get from a date column the last date of the previous month?

It depends on your RDBMS, so let's take the opportunity to make a generic answer:

In Oracle:

```
LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(mydate ,-1))
```

In MySQL:

```
LAST_DAY(mydate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

In SQL Server:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, mydate )-1, -1)
-- or simply:
EOMONTH(DATEADD(Month, -1, mydate ))
```

In Postgres:

```
date_trunc('month', now())::mydate - 1
```

Comment: so let me explain better. @GMB
assume this. e_date is +2. it may seem it is not but saturday and sundays and holidays are excluded.

a_date  e_date
2019-05-31 2019-06-04
2019-05-30 2019-06-03

I am not quite sure that the function 
`DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, mydate )-1, -1)` works.

Comment: In SQL Server it's simply `SELECT EOMONTH(DATEADD(Month, -1, GETDATE()))` which will returns `31/08/2019`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN dateadd(month,1+datediff(month,0,A_date),-1)< DATEADD(day, 2, A_date) THEN dateadd(month,1+datediff(month,0,A_date),-1) ELSE DATEADD(day, 2, A_date) END E_date
```

FOR input of 2019/09/30 output is 2019-09-30 00:00:00.000

Comment: Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'settle_date', table 'tempdb.dbo.#date 0000000000D2'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Comment: check your settle_date column is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EOMONTH()** in SQLServer to get the last day of the month.

Example:

```
EOMONTH(A_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is. What I've understood so far is that you want the last date of the month in case when adding two days to `A_Date` jumps to the next month.

Why don't you use `CASE WHEN` and compare out the months, this way :

```
DECLARE @A_Date date = '2019/09/30';
DECLARE @A_Date_Month int = 0;
DECLARE @E_Date_Month int = 0;

SELECT @A_Date_Month = Month(Cast(@A_Date AS datetime));
SELECT @E_Date_Month = Month(DATEADD(day, 2, @A_Date));

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN @A_Date_Month = @E_Date_Month 
        THEN DATEADD(day, 2, @A_Date) 
        ELSE EOMONTH(@A_Date) END AS OUTPUTValue
```

Try out the above set and do let me know if it resolves your issue!

Comment: As you allude to, this does not technically answer the O/P's actual question (30th or 31st), though it seems likely to address what the O/P actually wants (last 2 days of any month).

Answer (score 0):

> have two date columns, which takes into account only working days. A_date and E_date. E_date is calculated adding +2 days to A_date, because that's the request

I would simply do:

```
(case when dateadd(day, 2, a_date) < eomonth(a_date)
      then dateadd(day, 2, a_date)
      else eomonth(a_date)
 end) as e_date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want this only on the 30th or 31st of any given month and not the last 2 days of any month (since obviously not every month has 31 days) --

```
select A_date
   ,case when day(A_date) >= 30
       then eomonth(A_date)
       else dateadd("dd",2,A_date)
    end as E_date
```

Other answers work for "last 2 days of any month".